# Error while connecting from another device on the network,using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql v6

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework-core

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 433
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 363
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 94
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 124
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 915
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 406
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 369
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.AutoDetect(String connectionString)
   at MadaSoft.AddDbContextHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetMySql>b__0(DbContextOptionsBuilder o) in D:\VS Projects\MadaProject\MadaSoft\HostBuilder\AddDbContextHostBuilderExtensions.cs:line 32
   at MadaSoft.ContextFactoryApp.CreateDbContext() in D:\VS Projects\MadaProject\MadaSoft\_DbContext\ContextFactoryApp.cs:line 19
   at MadaSoft.App.MigrateContextApp() in D:\VS Projects\MadaProject\MadaSoft\App.xaml.cs:line 63
   at MadaSoft.App.OnStartupTask() in D:\VS Projects\MadaProject\MadaSoft\App.xaml.cs:line 55
   at MadaSoft.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in D:\VS Projects\MadaProject\MadaSoft\App.xaml.cs:line 35
```

You register the service as follows

```
            Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> configureDbContext = o =>
            {
                o.UseMySql(connectionString,ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
                o.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            }; 

            services.AddDbContext<ContextApp>(configureDbContext);
            services.AddSingleton(new ContextFactoryApp(configureDbContext));
```

When connecting from the same computer, the connection is correct.. but when connecting from another computer, the problem appears

This is the connection string
server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=dbName; Uid=root; Pwd=root; sslmode=none; CharSet=utf8;

Comment: Sorry.. the connection string is:
server=10.100.102.123; Port=3306; Database=dbName; Uid=root; Pwd=root; sslmode=none; CharSet=utf8;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks stackoverflow members.. I tried until I found the answer.. the error was due to using the default user (root).. I created a new user in the database engine, and gave it permissions.. and >>>> OK >>> problem was fixed